# Dart Ioc Container

Tags: dependency-injection, factory-method, fluent-interface, dart, flutter

This package is on pub dev [here](https://pub.dev/packages/ioc_container)

It's on Github [here](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/ioc_container/tree/20bc2c5e6efcb14db37e243958f5738e24f09cee)

```dart
class IocContainer {
  final Map<Type, Object Function(IocContainer container)> _map;
  IocContainer(this._map);

  T get<T>() => _map[T]!(this) as T;
}

class IocContainerBuilder {
  final Map<Type, Object Function(IocContainer container)> _map = {};
  IocContainerBuilder add<T>(T Function(IocContainer container) get) {
    _map.putIfAbsent(T, () => get as Object Function(IocContainer container));
    return this;
  }

  IocContainer toContainer() => IocContainer(
      Map<Type, Object Function(IocContainer container)>.unmodifiable(_map));
}

extension Extensions on IocContainerBuilder {
  IocContainerBuilder addSingleton<T>(T service) => add((i) => service);
}
```

This is a Dart implementation of an Ioc container. It's so simple that I feel like I've missed something. It handles singletons and transient dependencies but you would need to handle any other kinds of life spans yourself.

Here are some tests:

```dart
import 'package:ioc_container/ioc_container.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

class A {
  final String name;
  A(this.name);
}

class B {
  final A a;
  B(this.a);
}

class C {
  final B b;
  C(this.b);
}

class D {
  final B b;
  final C c;
  D(this.b, this.c);
}

class AFactory {
  final Map<String, A> _as = {};
  A get(String name) {
    final a = A(name);
    _as.putIfAbsent(name, () => a);
    return a;
  }
}

class SomeService {
  late final A a;
  late final A aa;
  SomeService(AFactory factory) {
    a = factory.get('a');
    aa = factory.get('aa');
  }
}

void main() {
  test('Basic singleton', () {
    final a = A('a');
    final builder = IocContainerBuilder();
    builder.add((i) => a);
    builder.add((i) => B(a));
    final container = builder.toContainer();
    expect(container.get<B>().a, a);
  });

  test('Basic Singleton 2', () {
    final a = A('a');
    final builder = IocContainerBuilder();
    builder.addSingleton(a);
    builder.add((i) => B(a));
    final container = builder.toContainer();
    expect(container.get<B>().a, a);
  });

  test('Method chaining', () {
final a = A('a');
final builder = IocContainerBuilder();
builder
    .addSingleton(a)
    .add((i) => B(i.get<A>()))
    .add((i) => C(i.get<B>()))
    .add((i) => D(i.get<B>(), i.get<C>()));
final container = builder.toContainer();
var d = container.get<D>();
expect(d.c.b.a, a);
expect(d.c.b.a.name, 'a');
  });

  test('Named Key Factory', () {
    final builder = IocContainerBuilder();
    builder
        .addSingleton(AFactory())
        .add((container) => SomeService(container.get<AFactory>()));

    final container = builder.toContainer();
    var someService = container.get<SomeService>();
    expect(someService.a.name, 'a');
    expect(someService.aa.name, 'aa');
  });
}
```

Is there anything obviously missing here? Any bugs or issues?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything obviously missing here?

No, it is that simple. I recently implemented a generalized versions of the mediator pattern and it has a similar concept (Map with Types as keys). When you start implementing these patterns yourself all the magic disappears.

Think how you will solve this:

- You have a overall map to determine if the giving type is a Singleton/factory.
- For the singleton you have a map with types as key's and value's is the singleton's object. If it is a factory, just new up a the instance and return it.